# How do I write 'dummy-data' into a binary file?

Tags: c#, binary, flush

I got an assignment at my internship, which basically goes like this (Everything is to be made with C#, in Visual Studio 2013):

1. Create new binary file (specific folder)
2. Empty/delete file, if it already exists
3. Mark start-time (millisecond precision)
4. Write 10 GB of dummy data into file, as fast as possible.
   (Write data as chunks of 1024 byte dummy data, continue untill 10 GB has been written)
5. Mark end-time (millisecond precision)
6. Flush and close file
7. Output the time it took to write all 10 GB of data (end time - start time)
8. Output number of bytes per second.

Possible input parameters must be:

- Folder
- Total bytes (ex. 10GB)
- Bytes per chunk (ex. 1024)

Now I am not really interested in just getting handed a code that does this, as that teaches me nothing. I am interested in learning how this is done, understand it, so I can do it myself.

Please also note, that I understand this is not a site to go to, just to have somebody make your assignments - but also understand that I am very interested in learning this, and I do not know of anywhere else (besides my tutor, but I don't want to come asking him about stuff every 20 minutes :P)

Could somebody explain, or maybe redirect me somewhere? Maybe just give me a hint as of how its done?
I have been doing C# for ~2 weeks, but I have never written anything that creates files etc.

Comment: What part of the assignment are you having trouble with? Creating the file? Writing to the file? Generating dummy data? Getting the current time?

Comment: Well which *part* of it is causing problems at the moment? You've got the project broken into 8 tasks already - how far have you got with those tasks?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the size/length of the file?

Comment: I would recommend starting, getting as far as you can and then asking specific questions on parts you are stuck with.

Comment: Please, show us some code and explain which part is the one you have difficulties with.  You may want to look at System.IO.FileStream, System.Random

Comment: So far I'm stuck on the first part, creating the file of which the data has to be written into. I'm a complete newb with C#, programming over all.

Comment: Then perhaps you should have paid more attention in your classes ;) Either way, look at the Microsoft reference. Some hints are written below, but we can't do your homework for you.

Comment: Never had any classes, only this internship which started monday, and then just self thaught a few weeks before.

Comment: Take a look at this link in terms of writing to/creating a file, this will help you understand System.IO http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader also in terms of recording the time in which the process took, have a look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch this will allow you to record (in milliseconds) how long the process took. I understand this doesnt answer **all** of your questions however it should help somewhat.

Comment: Do not wanna be rude or anything, here is a tip. If you want to find something, just use [`Google`](http://www.google.com), type something like `C# my_question`, where *my_question* is a sentence containing proper words. Try using different words. Examples: `C# how create file`, `C# binary file`, `C# create binary file`.. of course some tasks will not be trivial (as already pointed by others), then you can come here and ask *this specific question*, not a bunch of questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create new binary file (specific folder)
>
> ...
>
> Flush and close file

C# uses a concept called *streams* for binary input/output.

Mandatory literature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t(v=vs.110).aspx

Both techniques are demonstrated on MSDN.

> Empty/delete file, if it already exists

Well, actually, you only have to check whether a file exists if you **don't** wish to overwrite it.

> Mark start-time (millisecond precision)
>
> ...
>
> Mark end-time (millisecond precision)
>
> ...
>
> Output the time it took to write all 10 GB of data (end time - start time)
>
> Output number of bytes per second.

Look around the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

> Write 10 GB of dummy data into file, as fast as possible. (Write data
>   as chunks of 1024 byte dummy data, continue untill 10 GB has been
>   written)

Finally, the meat of the program...

---

**Spoiler alert!**

---

You'll have to write a loop that writes 1024 bytes on every iteration until the total sum of bytes written reaches 10GB.

Below is a code example, but without error checking (since it's not a requirement). In the real world, you would obviously write code that handles exceptions too.

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    double fileSize = Math.Pow(10, 10); // 10 GB
    int bufferSize = 1024; // 1KB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; // Create an array of zero's

    for (int written = 0; written < fileSize; written += bufferSize)
    {
        // Write 1024 bytes (all zero's: 000000000000...0)
        fileStream.Write(
            array: buffer,
            offset: 0,
            count: bufferSize);
    }
    /* Optional inside a "using" block: */ fileStream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly did not want a finished solution :P

Comment: I know. I just couldn't help myself. To be fair, I did add a spoiler alert.

Comment: :)) Oh, and don't flush on every iteration of the for cycle. You should only flush explicitly if you need to, otherwise you're trying to go around various optimizations .NET and the OS are trying to use. For sequential writing with no "pauses" between writes, it's only going to make the performance worse (a bit on average, but in some scenarios, such as writing to *ehm* a floppy drive or a network share, it can be significant). The flush would only be needed at the end, but `Dispose` takes care of that anyway, so it's not needed even then. If you don't forget the `Dispose`...

Comment: I looked at your post here, and recreated it.
Same functions, other variables etc, but at least I know how it Works now. Problem is just that it does not.

Even by copy/pasting your code I get the error: `System.ArgumentException: Offest and length were out of bounds for the array or Count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source Collection.` This happens regardless of what I set the file size and the buffer size to.

I appreciate your help a lot though. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the `offset` parameter. It should always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `System.IO.File`. You want to create a file stream (the static `File.Create`), and then in a `using` clause, you're going to write data through that stream using `Stream.Write`. I'm not going to add more, you can find enough information on MSDN etc. But feel free to ask any questions if need be.

Also, to nitpick, `Mark start-time (millisecond precision)` is going to be quite tricky, since system date isn't going to guarantee you that kind of precision. So you can print out the milliseconds, but it's not going to be *accurate* to a millisecond. There's a specialized class for measuring time intervals, find it and use it :)

Comment: Thank you. I have never used File.Create, "using", or "Stream.Write" before, so this is why I am so unaware as of how to handle this assignment. I'll go do some research on those.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following to get you started:

- System.IO.FileStream
- System.IO.FileMode
- System.Random
- System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
- System.TimeSpan